# Could any Star Trek species see the Q Continuum, and the Q, as they truly are?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

In two Voyager episodes, trips to the Q Continuum are made. On both of these occasions one of the Qs had to "change the scenery," so that the humanoid brains of the away team could have some sort of understanding of what was going on. If the scenery was not changed, then the Continuum would be way beyond the comprehension of everyone, including Tuvok.

As it is with the appearance of the Q. Obviously, they are not humanoids---they appear in this form in order that humanoids can relate to them. A Q appearing in his true form would surely be beyond the ability of lower races to comprehend.

So, are any species from Star Trek lore capable of viewing the Q Continuum in its true form?

Comment: The problem with this is that our definition of "see" is almost certainly too constrained to have any real meaning in this context. You're asking whether anyone could see what the Q really look like, but do they really "look like" _anything_?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought that Q made comments which suggest that the Q do have a definite "shape," though it is inaccessible to "lower" lifeforms, of course.

Answer (score 13):

### TV/Film Canon

Capable? Yes, I'd expect that some of the god-like species seen in the TV show (especially the [Douwd](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Douwd), [Nagilum](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nagilum), [Trelane's parents](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Trelane%27s_parents) and the [Organians](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Organian)) would possess sufficient intellectual and inter-dimensional capacity to view the Q in something closer to their genuine form.

It's worth noting that [Quinn](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/210.htm) does stress that in the long history of the Q-Continuum, they've never had a single visitor, suggesting that no species has the true capability to join them.

> **QUINN:** *I apologise for their lack of hospitality, Captain.* **We're not
>   used to visitors here. In fact you are the only ones who've ever come.**
>
> **TUVOK:** *Then what is the purpose of the road?*
>
> **QUINN:** *The road takes us to the rest of the universe, then it leads
>   back here. An endless circle.*

Comment: The lack of visitors could also be that the Q have just not wanted or allowed any visitors prior to then.

Comment: According to Q-Space, there's a sign further down the road that says "YOU ARE NOW ENTERING THE Q CONTINUUM. NO PEDDLERS, VAGRANTS, OR ORGANIANS ALLOWED".

Comment: That seems to suggest that they don't want to entertain very often.

Comment: @Xantec - When was the last time you wanted peddlers or vagrants to turn up at your house?

Comment: As I've never had any stop by, it is hard for me to say.

Comment: The sign suggests that peddlers, vagrants, and those pesky Organians, actually have the capacity to enter the Continuum. You don't put up a sign telling people they can't come in, if it isn't possible for them to come in.

Comment: Unless you have a perverse sense of humor or the possibility exists that someone could come to the Q Continuum by accident (or in the case of the Organians, by design).

Answer (score 8):

Guinan specifically (not El Aurians generally), might be able to pierce the illusions.  [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/27031/1027) indicates that originally, *Generations* would explain Guinan's ability to detect alterations to the universe as being due to a part of her being in the nexus.  The extent of what she is able to perceive isn't really clear from *The Next Generation*, but at a minimum, she would be capable of knowing that the illusions of the Continuum are illusions.  When presented with reality, she'd know as much.  It's not clear if she could handle it.

For that matter, we don't know if most species would have any actual issues perceiving a Q or the Continuum in their natural state.  Q tend to be pretty boastful, so they're not the most reliable of sources on themselves.