# Guinan's fate in "Conundrum"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Guinan doesn't actually appear in the episode "Conundrum," but she was on the ship at that time, and that raised a question for me.

Is it safe to assume that the Satarran mind-eraser weapon worked on Guinan? If not, and she recognized that things weren't right, why didn't she say something?

In "Yesterday's Enterprise," history itself was changed, yet Guinan was able to recognize that something wasn't right.

Yes, I realize that Whoopi Goldberg wasn't in "Conundrum." But does anything in Star Trek works speak of Guinan's fate in this episode?

Comment: Was she on-board at that time? Maybe she was away from the Enterprise on holiday?

Comment: That is certainly possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## She probably didn't notice anything

I think it's safe to assume that the mind eraser affected Guinan as well. We have plenty of examples where Guinan has alerted Picard to her worries so the fact that we don't see this happening suggests that she too was affected (as mentioned in the question one is 'Yesterday's Enterprise').

It's important to remember that Guinan's 'powers' wouldn't be useful in this situation. Her powers seem to be limited to detecting changes in the space-time continuum, as explained on [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/El-Aurian):

> El-Aurians were extraordinarily sensitive to the space-time continuum itself

and in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6075/22917):

> Guinan, perhaps her whole species, is able to understand the 'correct' state of the universe

It is important to remember that in this scenario, there were **no alterations to time or reality**, rather just an impact on the crew's memory.  Guinan therefore *couldn't* detect that things 'weren't right', because there hadn't been any change to the space-time continuum!

Comment: I don't think that statement on memory alpha is clearly supported by anything in canon, it may just be some editor's interpretation of what we saw in "Yesterday's Enterprise" (and note the box in the article after that paragraph which calls into question that very statement). That said, I think it's a *plausible* speculation that Guinan had some kind of space-time continuum sense (whether this was characteristic of El-Aurians or due to her specific experience with the Nexus), especially given that Guinan probably *would* have said something in "Conundrum" if she noticed anything amiss.

Comment: @Hypnosifl which is why I said 'Her powers **seem** to be limited...' ;)

Comment: @Hypnosifl added a link to an answer from this site; I think it's reasonable conjecture that her powers are limited to sensing the 'correct' state of the universe.  In this situation then, because there were alterations to the computer and the crew's memories, Guinan would have been none-the-wiser